# When were Buddhist suttas written?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, history, canon

When were Buddhist suttas written?

Does anybody know any source with a compiled list of suttas and their approximate date of writing?

Comment: This question is partially answered here: [Which are considered to be the oldest suttas?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9855/254)

Answer (score 2):

On [this page](http://obo.genaud.net/backmatter/appendixes/chron.htm) and [this page](https://www.budsas.org/ebud/ebsut053.htm), you can find the "Chronology Of The Pali Canon" by Dr. Bimala Churn Law.

Here, it is written in the beginning:

> Rhys Davids in his Buddhist India (p. 188) has given a chronological
>   table of Buddhist literature from the time of the Buddha to the time
>   of Asoka which is as follows:--
>
> 1. The simple statements of Buddhist doctrine now found, in identical words, in paragraphs or verses recurring in all the books.
> 2. Episodes found, in identical words, in two or more of the existing books.
> 3. The Silas, the Parayana, the Octades, the Patimokkha.
> 4. The Digha, Majjhima, Anguttara, and Samyutta Nikayas.
> 5. The Sutta-Nipata, the Thera-and Theri-Gathas, the Udanas, and the Khuddaka Patha.
> 6. The Sutta Vibhanga, and Khandhkas.
> 7. The Jatakas and the Dhammapadas.
> 8. The Niddesa, the Itivuttakas and the Patisambbhida.
> 9. The Peta and Vimana-Vatthus, the Apadana, the Cariya-Pitaka, and the Buddha-Vamsa.
> 10. The Abhidhamma books; the last of which is the Katha-Vatthu, and the earliest probably the Puggala-Pannatti.

But later, after in-depth analysis, the author comes to the conclusion:

> The results arrived at concerning the chronology of the Pali canonical
>   listerature are preseented in the subjoined table:
>
> (1) The simple statements of Buddhist doctrines now found, in identical words, in paragraphs or verses recurring in all the books.
>
> (2) Episodes found, in identical works, in two or more of the existing books.
>
> (3) The Silas, the Parayana group of sixteen poems without the prologue, the atthaka group of four or sixteen poems, the sikkhapadas.
>
> (4) The Digha, Vol. l, the Majjhima, the Samyutta, the Anguttara, and earlier Patimokkha code of 152 rules.
>
> (5) The Digha, Vols. II & III, the Thera-Theri-Gatha, the collection of 500 Jatakas, the Suttavibhanga, the Partisambhidamagga,
>   the Puggala-pannatti and the Vibhanga.
>
> (6) The Mahavagga and the Cullavagga, the Patimokkha code completing 227 rules, the Vimanavatthu and Petavatthu, the Dhammapada
>   and the Kathavatthu.
>
> (7) The Cullaniddesa, the Mahaniddesa, the Udana, the Itivuttaka, the Suttanipata, the Dhatukatha, the Yamaka and the Patthana.
>
> (8) The Buddhavamsa, the Cariyapitaka and the Apadana.
>
> (9) The Parivarapatha.
>
> (10) The Khuddakapatha.

But there is no table available listing each sutta with its date of writing.